# My functions are not running

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, termination

Working with random functions and doing 3 things with 3 different functions, the first gives me values from 1,10 randomly displayed in a list of 10 integers. The second gives me a list values 1,10 and squares them. Then last but not least the third singles out numbers that can be divided by three. The problem is my program is not running while on eclipse the program has no errors, yet my program terminates without printing anything. Please help me...

```
import random

def main():

def rand10():
    my_list = []
    for _ in xrange(10):
        my_list.append(random.randint(0,10))
    print my_list

def squareint_():
    squares = []
    for _ in xrange(0,10):
        squares.append(random.randint(0,10))**2
    print squares


def div3():
    divlist = []
    num = range(1,10)
    if (num % 3 == 0):
        for _ in xrange(20):
            divlist.append(random.randint(0,10))
        print divlist



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're only defining functions; you're not actually executing any of them.

Comment: Also, your indentation is off, or you've got other problems.  This should throw a syntax error at the second `def`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just calling `main()` not any of the `functions`  nested inside `main()`,

Using if `__name__ == '__main__':` does not magically call all your functions.

If your `main` function was like:

```
def main():
    squareint_()
    div3()
    rand10()
```

then you would be calling the other functions as it is, `main` does nothing or returns nothing.

As far as your methods go, `squares.append(random.randint(0,10))**2` is not valid, you cannot use `**` on a list method.

It needs to be inside the `paren` `squares.append(random.randint(0,10)**2)`

Also `num` is a list so you cannot use `if num % 3 == 0:`

You could use something like:

```
def div3():
    divlist = []
    num = range(1,10)
    for n in num: # loop over the list elements
        if n % 3 == 0:
            for _ in xrange(20):
                divlist.append(random.randint(0,10))
    print divlist
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two current problems with the code:

1. You're defining your functions inside `main()`, which is allowed but it's not very good coding practice. If you do this, then you can only ever use these functions from inside `main()`.
2. You're not actually calling any of your functions, you're just defining them. They need to be called with `rand10()`, `squareint_()` or `div3()`.

Try this bit of code instead, which fixes both issues:

```
import random

def rand10():
    my_list = []
    for _ in xrange(10):
        my_list.append(random.randint(0,10))
    print my_list

def squareint_():
    squares = []
    for _ in xrange(0,10):
        squares.append(random.randint(0,10))**2
    print squares


def div3():
    divlist = []
    num = range(1,10)
    if (num % 3 == 0):
        for _ in xrange(20):
            divlist.append(random.randint(0,10))
        print divlist

def main():
    rand10()
    squareint_()
    div3()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Of course, if your functions are invalid, then they will need to be fixed on their own. This just solves the issue of nothing happening when you execute your code. Now when you run the project in Eclipse, you'll see some errors and be able to fix them properly.